# How can I determine whether a function was overridden at compile time?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, overriding, compiler-warnings

Maybe a silly question.

Suppose I have the following:

```
class A{
     int x;
     int y;
     virtual int get_thing(){return x;}
};

class B : public A {
     int get_think(){return y;}
};
```

In the example above, B::get_thing returns x because the overriding code has a typo.

How can I ensure, *at compile time* that the get_thing function has been overridden in class B so that it returns y?

Comment: In that particular case it is quite simple: non-virtual functions are never *overridden*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Right, typos in the example. What I meant was, I didn't make A _pure_ virtual for a reason.

Comment: What is it that you really want? To force the implementor of `B` to override the function? To ensure that the signature of `get_thing` is the same as the virtual function in the base?

Comment: No, I want to be able to indicate to the compiler that I am _intending_ to override a base class function with something I have written in a derived class, and to have it warn me if the function in question is _not_ overriding a base class function.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you *not* want to use pure virtual to achieve this? I know it will potentially have other side effects, but it seems quite an obvious solution to your problem.

Comment: @Component10 An existing library that is somewhat unpleasant to alter. Also, if I have a dozen or so classes that are all happily using A::get_thing, then it seems peculiar to introduce an intermediate "C: public A" that just implements a what used to be A::get_thing and now becomes the parent of all the old children of A just to facilitate proper inheritance checking in B.

Comment: @JohnDoucette A fair point - it could get quite messy. Sounds like `override` is your best answer then, if you can access C++11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `A::get_thing` is virtual, and assuming `class B` is derived from `class A`, and you have C++11 support, you can use the [`override` special identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final):

```
class B : public A{
     int get_think() override {return y;}
};
```

This would produce a compiler error. Note that this is based on the signature of the method, i.e. its name, cv qualifiers, and types of the parameters. The return type or the body of the function do not come into it.

Comment: Ah! That's exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for figuring that out in spite of the errors my example code!

Comment: The `override` non-keyword will only ensure that the signature matches that of a virtual function in the base, but it will not *ensure that `get_thing` has been overridden in class B* and much less *that it returns y*

Comment: Was there a way to do something like this prior to C++11?

Comment: @JohnDoucette I am not aware of any clean and non-intrusive way to do it before C++11.

Comment: Microsoft's compiler has supported the override keyword since VS2005 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8ew2153(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

First you have an error in your example, I think `B` supposed to be a child of `A`, isn't it?!

But answer is: you can compare address of functions( of course if you want it and can't check it in programming time ):

```
if( reinterpret_cast<void*>(&B::get_think) != reinterpret_cast<void*>(&A::get_think) ) {
    std::cout << "B override A";
} else {
    std::cout << "B override A";
}
```

Comment: You cannot convert a PMF to a void* like that, and it's certainly not a compiler error.